# Why are there two phases of event propagation in browser？

Tags: javascript, browser, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

I know there are two phases of event propagation, **capturing** and **bubbling**. When one element is clicked, the event first propagates from outer element to the clicked element and this phase is called as **capturing**. Then the event propagates from the clicked element to the outer element and this phase is called **bubbling**. I want to know what the purpose is for the design of **capturing** and **bubbling** and is it enough for browser only supports **capturing** or **bubbling**.

Comment: The flexibility is useful for developers

Comment: If it doesn't support both, it's not a (standard-compliant) browser :-)

Comment: Downvote for lack of research effort. What resources did you read about dom event flow, and did they not give any examples of handling events in both of the two phases?

Comment: Modern browser support both of capturing and bubbling. There is a link which explains capturing and bubbling, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture.

Comment: *In modern browsers, by default, all event handlers are registered for the bubbling phase.* But you can use the following method to make the handler be registered for the capturing phase. ``element.addEventListener('click', handler, true)`` The third parameter means should the handler executes in the capturing phase.

Comment: There is demo about how to execute event handler in different phase. https://codepen.io/imechzhangly/pen/GRJLNjw

Comment: This answer has a bit of historical context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/8338 In short, the capturing model came from Netscape, and the bubbling model from Internet Explorer. Then both were standardized. There's no deeper meaning to having two instead of one.